# Riak Java Client annotation not recognized in Scala case class?

Tags: java, scala, riak

I am using case classes to define different "models" of data in our app. Reason is to enable easy use of Jerkson (Scala interface to Jackson). To convert my `User` to a domain object in Riak I have used the `@RiakKey` annotation on my guid. I have the following:

```
case class User(
  @RiakKey val guid: String,

  @RiakIndex(name = "email") val email: String,

  val salt: String,

  val passwordHash: String,

  val emailHash: String,

  val firstName: String,

  val lastName: String,

  val suspended: Boolean=false,

  val created: Timestamp=now

)
```

When I go to perform a domain conversion on the case class, the `@RiakKey` isn't recognized. It throws an `NoKeySpecifedException`. Here's my converter:

```
class UserConverter(val bucket: String) extends Converter[User] {

  def fromDomain(domainObject: User, vclock: VClock) = {
    val key = getKey(domainObject)

    if(key == null) throw new NoKeySpecifedException(domainObject)

    val kryo = new Kryo()
    kryo.register(classOf[User])

    val ob = new ObjectBuffer(kryo)
    val value = ob.writeObject(domainObject)

    RiakObjectBuilder.newBuilder(bucket, key)
        .withValue(value)
        .withVClock(vclock)
        .withContentType(Constants.CTYPE_OCTET_STREAM)
        .build()
  }
}
```

Is this an issue in Scala with Java annotations? Is there a workaround?

### Update

Here's where the User object is created and stored, and where the converter is referenced:

1)

```
val user = parse[User](body) // jerkson parse, body is a string of JSON
User.store(user)
```

2)

```
object User {

  val bucketName = "accounts-users"
  val bucket = DB.client.createBucket(bucketName).execute()

  def fetch(id: String) = bucket.fetch(id).execute().getValueAsString()

  def store(o: User) = bucket.store( o ).withConverter(new UserConverter(bucketName)).execute()

}
```

**Strack Trace**

```
com.basho.riak.client.convert.NoKeySpecifedException
        at com.basho.riak.client.bucket.DefaultBucket.store(DefaultBucket.java:455)
        at com.threetierlogic.AccountService.models.User$.store(User.scala:58)
        at com.threetierlogic.AccountService.controllers.Users$$anonfun$routes$3.apply(Users.scala:54)
        at com.threetierlogic.AccountService.controllers.Users$$anonfun$routes$3.apply(Users.scala:51)
```

Comment: It should work, from what I've read (I haven't written anything with scala). I know this is a dumb question but I just want to check ... you've set `guid` to something other than `null` in the `User` object being passed into the store operation, yes? Are you using your own Mutation and ConflictResolver as well?

Comment: Not using my own Mutation and ConflictResolver, is it necessary? Guid is set as a string of "0u0700fs984". I'm posting some dummy JSON and storing it in Riak, but the parsing of the JSON checks out OK.

Comment: Is it possible when Jackson parses the incoming JSON the annotations get lost?

Comment: No - not necessary (just wanted to check) and if not supplied the defaults basically are what you would expect (siblings aren't supported and whatever you pass in to the store call gets stored regardless of anything existing in Riak). Annotations are just markers in Java/Scala; they aren't stored with the object data (The `toDomain()` in the converter uses them to know where to put the retrieved data).

Comment: Edit: if i comment out the `throw new NoKeySpecifed` line it looks like it is actually being thrown when the store method is called. I wonder if the RiakObjectBuilder isn't returning a key.

Comment: Well, it sort of does - it's not your converter :) The `DefaultBucket.store(T o)` checks for the key and that's what's throwing it. Can you post your code where you're creating the `User` object and passing it to the `Bucket.store()` method? (This is *way* before the converter is involved)

Comment: Yep just added it at the end.

Comment: If that JSON contains a `guid` field with a String value in it and the `User` object is getting populated with it ... I'm at the end of my expertise. Googling java annotations and scala I can't find anything other than "should just work".

Comment: Would a workaround be to use `DomainBucket.store` and I need to "build" a domain bucket? Saw something in comments at the top of `DomainBucket.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I apologize for the long conversation before this answer)

After learning a bit more about scala I discovered that with a *case class* you have to do it a little differently.

http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/10/scala-case-classes-and-annotations-part-1.html

If you do:

```
@(RiakKey@field) guid: String
```

it works.

I wrote a small test program in scala and was able to extract the annotated key using the static `getKey()` method used in the `DefaultBucket` that was returning null and causing the exception to be thrown.

```
import com.basho.riak.client.convert.KeyUtil.getKey;

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val u = User("my_key")
    val k = getKey(u)
    System.out.println(k);

  }
}
```

User.scala

```
/* scala 2.9.1 would be scala.annotation.target.field */
import scala.annotation.meta.field
import com.basho.riak.client.convert.RiakKey;

case class User (@(RiakKey@field) guid: String)
```

Output:

> my_key

(And, if you change the annotation back to the way you had it, it returns `null` as expected)

Comment: wow learned something new today myself. Looks like i need to fix the index annotations, too. thank you very much for posting this! scala devs on riak everywhere will cheer!

Comment: Glad I could help :) You can always ping us directly on the [Riak-Users mailing list](http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com) as well

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll also note the import for Scala 2.9.1 is `import scala.annotation.target.field` looks like the package structure changed in 2.10

Answer (score 0):

Here's my proposed workaround for the problem. Instead of relying on annotations, I am just going to use the `DefaultBucket.store` method and manually designate a key.

My User companion object:

```
object User {

  val bucketName = "accounts-users"
  val bucket = DB.client.createBucket(bucketName).execute()

  def store(key: String, o: User) = bucket.store(key, o).withConverter(new UserConverter(bucketName)).execute()

}
```

And using it:

```
val user = parse[User](body)
User.store(user.guid, user)
```

Comment: Figured it out. It was going to drive me insane otherwise. Sorry for my lack of scala knowledge causing this to be more difficult that it should have been :) Posted the answer.